# Python Key Value Error (Json)

Tags: python, json, http, key

I am trying to grab this data and print into a string of text i am having the worst! issues getting this to work.

Here is the source i am working with to get a better understanding i am working on an envirmental controller and my sonoff switch combined 
https://github.com/FirstCypress/LiV/blob/master/software/liv/iotConnectors/sonoff/sonoff.py  this code works for two pages once completed so ignore the keys for tempature etc

```
    m = json.loads(content)
co2  = m["Value"]
```

I need the value of "Value" under the "TaskValues" it should be either a 1 or a 0 in almost any case how would i pulled that key in the right form?

```
"Sensors":[
{
"TaskValues": [
{"ValueNumber":1,
"Name":"Switch",
"NrDecimals":0,
"Value":0
}],
"DataAcquisition": [
{"Controller":1,
"IDX":0,
"Enabled":"false"
},
{"Controller":2,
"IDX":0,
"Enabled":"false"
},
{"Controller":3,
"IDX":0,
"Enabled":"false"
}],
"TaskInterval":0,
"Type":"Switch input - Switch",
"TaskName":"relias",
"TaskEnabled":"true",
"TaskNumber":1
}
],
"TTL":60000
}
```

Comment: This does not seems to be a valid json string

Comment: @mad_ I think he's just missing the outer `{`, could be just copy-paste error

Comment: i fixed it thanks yea i only posted a bit of the code because i just wanted that function before i add it into the python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by

```
 m['Sensors'][0]['TaskValues'][0]['Value']
```

Comment: This seems to be working but the value shows either 0.0 or 1.0 Any idea why? i mean i am happy with this but

Comment: @BryanSummers: weird, are the values in `content` surely integers??

Comment: That was the issue changed it to int and bam perfect.

Answer (score 0):

`"Value"` is nested in your json, as you've mentioned. To get what you want, you'll need to traverse the parent data structures:

```
m = json.loads(content)
# This is a list
a = m.get('Sensors')

# This is a dictionary
sensor = a[0]

# This is a list
taskvalue = sensor.get('TaskValues')

# Your answer
value = taskvalue[0].get('Value')
```